# GitKit Sign In Button not Working on mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, federated-identity, mobile-browser, google-identity-toolkit

I have recently delved into using the Google Identity toolkit. The sign in flow works perfectly and as expected on chrome and firefox desktop browsers but does not work when trying it on mobile browsers. Any help would be appreciated as i am stuck.

The site in question is http://××××××.lemzdelivery.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on the [Identity Toolkit forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-identity-toolkit/f3XheMbbTV4).